# How to check if my EC2 instance is burstable? (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to check if my EC2 instance is burstable? (AWS)

I'm using Launch template it only said "Instance type t2.micro".

T2, T3, T3a, and T4g - Are they always burstable or should I specify "T2-burstable" / "T2-not-burstable"?

Comment: All of the t2, t3, t3a, t4g [instances are burstable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all the t instances type are burstable, an instance is considered **bursting** when its cpu usage goes above the following thresholds:

- nano 5%
- micro 10%
- small 20%
- medium 20%
- large 30%
- xlarge    40%
- 2xlarge   40%

if an instance consumes all its CPU credits it gets throttled at those same values.

to avoid this you can run your instance in unlimited mode for a little fee

Comment: My T2 micro is going 100% CPU usage sometimes, no throttling is noticed. Why?

Comment: when it goes past 10% usage it starts consuming the CPU credits (micro instances earn 12 credits per hour) so as long as you have cpu credits it won't be throttled. if you select your instance and click the monitoring panel you'll see in the plotted graphics down below `CPU credit balance` and `CPU credit usage`

Comment: if you have 0 credits and it's still not throttling it's because it's running in unlimited mode, so you pay some extra fee when you have 0 credit and still go past 10%

Answer (score 0):

All of the t2, t3, t3a, t4g instances are burstable